# A condition of For Loop not Working in java

Tags: java, for-loop

I'm trying to Calculate SUM of Diagonal of a matrix. But it exclude an Element. I solve my problem using if-else but i didn't understand why for-loop not working. Please help !

```
public class sumDia {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int[][] A = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {6, 7, 8}};

        int i, j;
        int sum = 0;
        for(i = 0, j = 0; i == j && j < A.length; i++, j++) sum += A[i][j];

        // for(i = 0, j = A.length - 1; i != j && i < A.length && j >= 0; i++, j--) sum += A[i][j];
        // ( i != j ) Not Working... I don't know why

        for(i = 0, j = A.length - 1; i < A.length && j >= 0; i++, j--){
            if(i != j){
                sum += A[i][j];
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Sum of Diagonals is : " + sum);
    }
}
```

Diagonal : `[0][0] , [1][1] , [2][2] and [0][2] , [1][1] , [2][0]`.
In the 2nd Diagonal `[1][1]` is repeat that's why i removed it using (`i != j`)

NOTE : Problem in commented for-loop

Answer (score 2):

`i != j` why is this in for-loop condition? 
Diagonal elements index are `[0][0],[1][1],[2][2]` and `[0][2],[1][1],[2][0]`.
The 2nd diagonal have `[1][1]` where i==j, so the condition `i != j` will be false in 2nd iteration and will exit the for-loop, which ignores both the 2nd and 3rd element.

Comment: I assume he doesn't want to sum the center twice?

Comment: but that will ignore the 3rd element as well

Comment: Why? It doesn't exit the loop.

Comment: `for(i = 0, j = A.length - 1; i != j && i < A.length && j >= 0; i++, j--)` this

Comment: he was asking why 2nd for-loop is not working properly

Comment: Oh, I didn't realize the problem was in the commented code.

Comment: Yes problem in commented for-loop